# Solr Default Query in Admin UI does not work

Tags: solr

I am changing the default query for the UI in solrconfig.xml but it does not change the default query in the Admin UI. It says legacy config but I don't know where else I should change it to refresh the admin UI. I have reloaded the collection and restarted Solr.

```
 <!-- Legacy config for the admin interface -->
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by editing the query.html file in the /tpl directory of the webapp.

```
<textarea name="q" id="q" title="The query string.">*:*</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea why then it is still in solrconfig? The other thing I am doing is a default query in the request handler